# 3.3 v TLL to RS232 (To Connect Pic with PC)?

Tags: rs232, max232

Is there any ic like MAX232 that can level shift 3.3v TLL to RS232?

I need it to debug a pic running on 3.3 V with my pc.

Comment: Yes, there's a 3v3 version of the MAX232, it's on Maxim's website and everything.

Comment: @JohnU i couldn't find it. link me

Comment: MAX3232 - should be what you're looking for.

Comment: @TomL. along with a description that it's a 3.3v compatible version and maybe a link and a few details on the voltage range etc you could post that as an answer - it does seem to be the obvious answer.

Comment: What the hell,  got down voted, why the hatred? Max3232 is for 3V to 5V converter. Using Max3232 in series with Max232 would be an expensive and inefficient solution.

Comment: Look again - the MAX3232 is a 3v-to-RS232 driver, it will tolerate 3 to 5.5v supply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just purchase a TTL to 232 cable from FTDI.

It plugs into your USB port and you use Termite or whatever your flavor may be and start on your debug.

Below are the links.

http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/Cables/USBTTLSerial.htm

http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/Cables/DS_TTL-232R_CABLES.pdf

you can get it for $20 @ digikey

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/TTL-232R-3V3/768-1015-ND/1836393

I use this on every design. Just run the TTL lines to a header and you are good to go.

Good luck!